# App para páginas curtidas em comum no facebook

Tags: facebook

A um tempo atrás a opção "ver amizade" mostrava também as páginas curtidas em comum, porém foi retirada de lá e pelo que eu vi não existe mais em lugar nenhum.

Um tempo atrás eu fiz essa pergunta no support do facebook e não obtive uma resposta decente. 
A única resposta que eu obtive foi de um colaborador alegando "Privacidade", porém, se você for no */likes* de qualquer perfil(seja amigo ou não), você consegue ver TODAS as páginas que essa pessoa curtiu. Essa "privacidade" não faz sentido.  Se eu posso ver todas as páginas curtidas de uma outra pessoa, qual o problema de existir um filtro informando quais dela são em comum comigo?

Tinder:
o tinder faz isso, porém, só compara os 100 últimas páginas curtidas de ambos perfis, além de ter a necessidade do match, enfim, definitivamente o tinder não é o ambiente para isso.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma ferramenta destinada à essa função, ou se é simples escanear as páginas curtidas e um perfil e comparar, através da API.

Obrigado.

Comment: Advogar se a política de privacidade do facebook faz sentido ou não acho que não vem ao caso, e na minha opinião se foi removido com certeza tiveram algum motivo no mínimo válido (mesmo que não seja do nosso conhecimento). Até onde eu saiba, não tem nenhuma outra ferramenta *oficial* além da graph api, fugir disso será de terceiros, porém a forma mais direta seria buscar as páginas curtidas pelas duas pessoas e comparar o retorno.